# Configure ldap for SSL/TLS

Tags: ssl, openldap, slapd

Configure OPENLDAP for SSL/TLS. Basically i need to configure ldap for secure connection on port like 636. Currently i have seen many articles to configure it in Linux(CentOS 7). But all are using slapd.config file but in my installation i am not able to find this file. Please suggest any methods to configure without this file or suggest way to find/create this file. Reasons for missing of this file is not getting .I am new in this area so please help.

Comment: Yes Sorry its TLS

Comment: You're probably using online configuration, which means a system of LDIF files under a `slapd.d` directory, but if so the idea is not to edit those files but to connect to the server with an LDAP browser and reconfigure it online.